# Split and match string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to select all rows where range address's are equal

**Table**

```
  id    Address
    1   5419-5436 East hancock Street, Somerset, VA
    2   251 West Churchill Road, Arlington, TX
    3   981-981 Main Street , norman, OK
    4   615-615 Mountain Ave, Bridgewater, NJ
```

**Output**

```
id  Address
3   981-981 Main Street , norman, OK
4   615-615 Mountain Ave, Bridgewater, NJ
```

The address number 981-981,615-615 are equal. 5419-5436 is not selected since it's have different address range.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm clueless from where to start..New to Mysql

Comment: 1) Select all values 2) split the nvarchar by blank (' ') 3) Split new values by '-', 4) compare them. Also have a look at Database normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from your_table where
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address,'-',-1),' ',1)=SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address,'-',1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to select the portions on either side of the '-' and compare them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address, '-', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Address, '-', -1), ' ', 1)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
id    Address
3     981-981 Main Street , norman, OK 
4     615-615 Mountain Ave, Bridgewater, NJ
```

Note this code assumes that the numbers are followed by a space.

Comment: @min2bro You should accept this answer, as it was poster faster than currently accepted one and is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Sample data:

```
create table tbl(txt varchar(100));
insert into tbl values
('5419-5436 East hancock Street, Somerset, VA'),
('251 West Churchill Road, Arlington, TX'),
('981-981 Main Street , norman, OK'),
('615-615 Mountain Ave, Bridgewater, NJ');
```

T-SQL below. In inner query we select whole address and the range address extracted and filter out those records that don't have hyphen (`-`). In outer query we split `RangeAddress` by hyphen (`-`) and compare to parts of `RangeAddress`. Based on that we filter resultset.

```
select txt from (
    select txt,
           substring(txt, 1, locate(' ', txt) - 1) RangeAddress
    from tbl
    where locate('-', substring(txt, 1, locate(' ', txt) - 1)) > 0
) a 
where substring(RangeAddress, 1, locate('-', RangeAddress) - 1) = 
                 substring(RangeAddress, locate('-', RangeAddress) + 1);
```